# Remove the first N elements from an array while reducing the N variable

Tags: php

I'm trying to remove the first `$offset` elements from an array and reduce the offset for future adds to the array. The loop must also end if I reach the end of the array.

```
$max1 = $offset;
$max2 = count($elements);
for ($i=0; ($i<$max1 && $i<$max2); $i++) {
    unset($elements[$i]);
    $offset--;
}
```

I'm trying to find a better way to do it. At least a way to use the values of `$offset` and `count($elements)` (which are changing) without having to create aux variables.

Comment: What task does this code accomplish? Please tell us, and also make that the title of the question via [edit]. Maybe you missed the placeholder on the title element: "_State the task that your code accomplishes. Make your title distinctive._". Also from  [How to Ask](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask): "_State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it._".

Comment: What @SamOnela said. You were given the exact same advice when you posted this question on StackOverflow.

Comment: I'm trying to be as much specific as I can. I changed the title but I think the task is clear, I don't really know what could be unclear in the description.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Code style

### Variable names

Make sure that your variable names are descriptive of what they contain. In particular `$max1` and `$max2` use a poor naming style as it is unclear what you expect them to contain.

### Whitespace

Make sure to keep whitespace around your operators, even in a for-loop. This increases readability, and thus decreases the chance for bugs.

### Unneeded bookkeeping

You currently use `$offset--;` but do not use the result. Remove code you do not use.

## Bugs

Your current code only works once, because you keep the keys. Considering the following code:

```
$offset = 3;
$elements = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13];

$max1 = $offset;
$max2 = count($elements);
for ($i=0; ($i<$max1 && $i<$max2); $i++) {
    unset($elements[$i]);
    $offset--;
}

$max1 = $offset;
$max2 = count($elements);
for ($i=0; ($i<$max1 && $i<$max2); $i++) {
    unset($elements[$i]);
    $offset--;
}

var_dump($elements);

// Result: array(11) { [3]=> int(3) [4]=> int(4) [5]=> int(5) [6]=> int(6) [7]=> int(7) [8]=> int(8) [9]=> int(9) [10]=> int(10) [11]=> int(11) [12]=> int(12) [13]=> int(13) }
```

You would expect it to remove the first 3 elements twice, but because the keys are not reset, the second iteration of your code will try to remove key 0, 1 and 2, while the first key is 3.

## Algorithm

Your current code modifies an array in-place while keeping the keys. Modifying arrays while looping over them is aweful in any language, as you need to be mindful that conditions in loops may be pre-calculated, and element pointers may skip elements.

Since you use a for-loop, I can assume you use an array with numeric keys, which makes it odd that you would want to keep the current keys.

### Alternative creating a new array

In php you can use `array_slice` to obtain a new array with only a slice of the original array. This will reset the keys of the array.

```
$elements = array_slice($elements, $offset);
```

No loop required.

### Alternative deleting elements

You can use `array_splice` to modify an array in-place by deleting a consecutive chunk of array elements. It returns the deleted elements and the original array has a few less elements. This will also reset the keys.

```
array_splice($elements, 0, $offset);
```

Again, no loop required.

### Alternative with a loop

You can also use a loop and use `array_shift` to remove the first element of the array repeatedly. For numeric keys the keys are reset, while literal keys are left untouched.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $offset; $i++) {
  $result = array_shift($elements);
  if (is_null($result)) {
    // The array is empty, so safe us some time
    break;
  }
}
```

### Filter to keep keys

If we want to keep keys, we can use `array_filter`. The following code works exactly like your own code, as in: It works the first time you invoke it, and then it breaks.

```
$elements = array_filter(
  $elements,
  function ($item, $index) use ($offset) {
    return $index >= $offset;
  },
  ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH
);
```

You can improve that code by using and checking against `$offset + $first_key`.

```
reset($elements);
$first_key = key($array);
```